# AVPlayerViewController full screen issue (iOS 9 beta 2)

Tags: ios, avplayer, mpmovieplayer

I am migrating from MPMoviePlayer to AVPlayer/AVPlayerViewController. Everything works fine, except that when I zoom to full screen via the on screen control, after the movie finished playing, the full screen mode does not go away and stuck there. I am running this on iOS 9 beta 2.

Here's my code:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.playerController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
self.playerController.view.frame = self.imageView.frame;

[self.view addSubview:self.playerController.view];
[self.playerController.player play];

NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopVideo:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
```

When the movie stop, I run the following stopVideo code:

```
[self.playerController.player pause];
[self.playerController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Is it my code or is this an iOS 9 bug?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue